# ProGuard issue with Google Play Service and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, android-proguard

I am getting following warnings from Proguard for firebase messaging after upgrading Google Play services and related Libraries.

1. Play Services: `9.4.0` -> `10.2.1`
2. MixPanel: `4.9.2` -> `4.9.8`
3. Intercom: `3.0.10` -> `3.1.3`

Here is proguard warnings from `com.google.firebase.messaging.*`

```
Warning: com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService: can't find referenced method 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg zzabT()' in program class com.google.firebase.iid.zzg
Warning: com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced field 'java.lang.String zzcvH' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbxz$zza
Warning: com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced field 'java.lang.String zzcvH' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbxz$zzb
Warning: com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced field 'java.lang.String zzcvI' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbxz$zzb
Warning: com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced field 'long zzcvJ' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbxz$zzb
Warning: com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced field 'java.lang.String zzcvK' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbxz$zzb
Warning: com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced field 'int zzcvL' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbxz$zzb
Warning: com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced field 'int zzcvM' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbxz$zzb
Warning: com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced field 'java.lang.String zzcvN' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbxz$zzb
Warning: com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced field 'java.lang.String zzcvO' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbxz$zzb
Warning: com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced field 'java.lang.String zzcvR' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbxz$zzb
Warning: com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced field 'int zzcvS' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbxz$zzb
Warning: com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced field 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbxz$zza[] zzcvT' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbxz$zzb
```

I'm using latest play services.

```
intercomLibraryVersion = '3.1.3' // https://github.com/intercom/intercom-android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
mixPanelVersion = '4.9.8' // https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android/releases
playServiceVersion = '10.2.1' // https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

// Google Play Services
// https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$rootProject.playServiceVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$rootProject.playServiceVersion"// used by - mixpanel & intercom

// Mixpanel
//https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android/releases
compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:$rootProject.mixPanelVersion"

// Intercom - live chat and analytics
// https://github.com/intercom/intercom-android
// https://developers.intercom.com/docs/android-installation
compile "io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:$rootProject.intercomLibraryVersion"
compile "io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-fcm:$rootProject.intercomLibraryVersion"
```

Only way I could avoid these warning was by adding following proguard rule.

```
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.messaging.**
```

Does anybody know side affect of this? or how to fix this firebase message issue.

**UPDATE # 1**
App now randomly crashes with following stacktrace.

```
04-06 14:49:28.911 25362-25455/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-13-thread-1
    Process: com.myapp, PID: 25362
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.google.firebase.iid.b.handleIntent(android.content.Intent)"
    at com.google.firebase.iid.b$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: For now, I have downgraded all versions to previously working one mentioned above.

Comment: The same issue appears with google play service 10.2.6, when trying to hock up the firebase monitoring with my app

Comment: @JafarAlali92 just curious, does the solution below work for you?

Answer (score 24):

This error usually appears when you forget to update firebase dependencies.

Firebase references MUST always be the same version as google dependencies.

This runs into your error:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
```

This solves the error:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1' //Updated
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1' //Updated
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1' //Updated
```

Hope it solves your problem

Comment: Currently I don't include firebase, but may be 3rd-party library does. Will double check the `gradle dependencies` to figure it out, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I have not tried to upgrade the libraries again. I see around `7` upvotes, so I am guessing your solution worked for few people. I will try again sometime soon and provide my update here.

Comment: This should the accepted solution! Thank you very much! Saved my day